# search using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

please visit this link : http://tndoctors.in/doctors.php

in that six drop down boxes are there na.... (STATE , DISTRICT , LOCATION , MEDICINE , SPECIALTY , GRADE)

I FETCHED ALL THE DATA FROM SQL DB TO ALL DROPDOWN BOXES.

I created table like

```
STATE (state id & state name) [st.id as primary key]

DISTRICT(district id , district name and used state id as foreign key here)

location (location id , location name and used district id as foreign key here)
```

as same above for medicine , specialty and grade....

and at last I created a table

```
DOCTOR_DETAIL ( name , address , reg.no , contact details , age , and specialty , grade , medicine , district and state)
```

for specialty , grade ,medicine , district and state I used the above tables id `(primary key)` as foreign key in the `doctor _detail` table

for example if I select

STATE: TAMILNADU
 DISTRICT: COIMBATORE
 LOCATION : some data
 medicine : allopathy
 speciality : cardiac surgeon
 grade    : some data....

If I select the above all things from drop down list.... and on clicking the go button...

I have to get the possible search results

Comment: Could you reformat this code? It's a bit slack.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table is the best option

```
SELECT * FROM DOCTOR_DETAIL
LEFT JOIN DISTRICT ON  DISTRICT.district id = DOCTOR_DETAIL.district id
LEFT JOIN STATE ON STATE.state_id = DOCTOR_DETAIL.state_id
..for all tables required
WHERE DISTRICT.name = '".$district_name."' AND SATET.name = '".$state_name."'
...For all filters that you reqiored
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this is not that ideal, as it's open to SQL injection attacks.  The fundamental premise is more or less sound (I think), but don't do string concatenation to build SQL queries

Comment: Yup.. i know i just explained the structure, he has to make the code secure :D